# Problem wrapping Extjs Accordion

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am tring to start and build an accordion menu.
I want to use it as an xtype or new MyVar(). but i get few JS Errors
this is my code:

```
var AccordionMenu = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    layout: 'accordion',
    id:'action-panel',
        region:'west',
        split:true,
        collapsible: true,
        collapseMode: 'mini',
        width:200,
        minWidth: 150,
        border: false,
        baseCls:'x-plain',

    items: [{
        title: 'Affiliates',
        html: 'Empty',
        cls: 'empty'
    },{
        title: 'Brands',
        html: 'Empty',
        cls: 'empty'
    }]
});

Ext.reg('accordion_menu', AccordionMenu);

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();


            var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
                layout:'border',
                items:[
                    new AccordionMenu()
                   ,
                   {
                    region:'center',
                    margins:'5 5 5 0',
                    cls:'empty',
                    bodyStyle:'background:#f1f1f1',
                    html:'test'
                }]
            });

});
```

this is the errors:

```
    this.items.add is not a function

Line 12777
```

Thanks

Comment: The `this.items.add` is not a function because it's a simple JSON object! It's trying to call the `add` function from `{
        title: 'Affiliates',
        html: 'Empty',
        cls: 'empty'
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code:

```
var AccordionMenu = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var config = {
            layout: 'accordion',
            region: 'west',
            split: true,
            width: 200,
            layout: 'accordion',
            animate: true,
            fill: true,
            items: [{
                title: 'Affiliates',
                html: 'Empty',
                cls: 'empty'
            },{
                title: 'Brands',
                html: 'Empty',
                cls: 'empty'
            }]
        };
        Ext.apply(config, cfg);
        AccordionMenu.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }
});

Ext.reg('accordion_menu', AccordionMenu);


Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:'border',
        items:[
            new AccordionMenu(),
        {
            region:'center',
            margins:'5 5 5 0',
            cls:'empty',
            bodyStyle:'background:#f1f1f1',
            html:'test'
        }]
    });
});
```

**Update**

So sorry for didn't notice I have written the item configurations into the prototype of the `Application` object, which causes your `this.items.add` cannot be called because they are basically simple json configurations!

The code has been fixed, please take a look and have a try. Should work :)

*Personal Suggestion*

If you are not going to share this components (use it in many places), I would suggest you to just create a Panel with the required configurations. Although creating components by extending other components is a good practice, but it is a lot more complicated and sometimes can cause problem just like I did earlier.

The code below should work also:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:'border',
        items:[{
            layout: 'accordion',
            region: 'west',
            split: true,
            width: 200,
            layout: 'accordion',
            animate: true,
            fill: true,
            items: [{
                title: 'Affiliates',
                html: 'Empty',
                cls: 'empty'
            },{
                title: 'Brands',
                html: 'Empty',
                cls: 'empty'
            }]
        },{
            region:'center',
            margins:'5 5 5 0',
            cls:'empty',
            bodyStyle:'background:#f1f1f1',
            html:'test'
        }]
    });
});
```

Although messy, but it's easy to understand, right?

Comment: Thanks but it is not working (already tried that), I have updated my post code.  so u can try it.

Comment: Hi fatnjazzy, I posted the update above, have a look :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Start with Ext.ns ('Application');